# Variable file may not have been initialized

Tags: c, file

Here is my function. My char `peca` is defined as `char peca[MAX_BUFFER]`, where `max_buffer` is 1024. I want to write in my "tabuleiro" file what is inside `peca`, but my program is always saying that file may not have been initialized.

So my function doesn't print my txt file, any ideas?

```
void write_txt (char *peca){
    FILE *file;
    fopen("tabuleiro.txt","w");
    fprintf(file,"M: %c\n",*peca);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: `FILE *file = fopen("tabuleiro.txt", "w");`

Comment: that was the problem, when i open the file i have to put file = fopen...and i forgot thanks1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So my function doesn't print in my txt file

Assign the return pointer of [`FILE* fopen(const char* filename, const char* mode );`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) to your file, like this:

```
file = fopen("tabuleiro.txt", "w");
```

Then, you would check if `file` is *not* `NULL`, after opening it, in order to know that it opened successfully.

Moreover, you probably want to write to the file using `%s`, which is intended for strings.

So, you could try this:

```
void write_txt (char *peca) {
    FILE *file = fopen("tabuleiro.txt", "w");
    if(!file) {
      printf("File did NOT open successfully!\n")
      // error handling here..do not execute the fprintf() or fclose()
    }
    fprintf(file,"M: %s\n",*peca);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: thanks, i it worked, but doesn't print in txt file anyway, i will see what is wrong